# Do any Latin animal names start with Q?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, animals

Ideally I'm looking for common or barnyard animals attested in the Classical period, but Late Latin or early Medieval Latin that has a good case of going back to the Classical period would suffice.

I thought about *quaccula*, but I don't think the word is very ancient.

Comment: I just looked through Whitaker's Words and the closest I found was [QUADRIIUGUS](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#quadriiugus), a four-horse team. Classically attested, but possibly not found in barnyards. (Thanks to a couple helpful folks on [CONLOQVIVM](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37266019#37266019).)

Comment: @BenKovitz If we go that route, *quadrupes* would work, too.

Comment: I assume scientific names w/o an ancient origin don't count

Comment: @Rafael I was really hoping for an actual ancient word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DuCange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/qualea) reports **qualea** (quail) with **qualia** (!) and **quaquilia** as alternate spellings. The work cited by DuCange, by Johannes de Janua, better known as Johannes Balbus (d. c. 1298), explains that the bird got its name from the sound it makes, "*quaquera*". Possibly this was a medieval development, as in classical Latin, this bird would be called a [*cōturnīx*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coturnix#Latin)—apparently also imitative. No word on the *vulgo,* so it's theoretically possible that ordinary folks in Ancient Rome said something that sounded like *qualea,* but the word for quail in both the Vulgate and Vetus Latina is [*coturnix*](https://books.google.com/books?id=06-8DgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA124&ots=5I3l8FT_a7&dq=coturnix%20vetus%20latina&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q=coturnix&f=false). The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155818?rskey=3n4bEG&result=1#eid)'s etymology of "quail" also reports the spellings **quaquila** and **quaila**, and **quaccola** from the 8th century.

By the way, **qualeæ** and similar birds are protected by [this law](https://books.google.com/books?id=HOIkaI3ENq4C&dq=%22Ius%20municipale%20Vicentinum%22&pg=PA268#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the 1628 edition of the *Ius municipale Vicentinum* against being caught with nets or hoods during April, May, and June.

---

[*The Birds of the Latin Poets*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oishAQAAIAAJ&dq=quail%20latin&pg=PA196#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Ernest Whitney Martin (1914) lists one bird whose name starts with Q: **querquedula**, "probably the Teal (*Anas crecca*) or the Garganey (*Anas querquedula*)."

Columella in *De Re Rustica* 8.15 writes:

> Nessotrophii cura similis, sed maior impensa est. Nam clausae pascuntur anates, **querquedulae**, boscides, phalerides, similesque volucres, quae stagna et paludes rimantur. …
>
> A place for rearing ducks requires similar attention but is more costly. For mallard, **teal**, garganey and coots and similar birds, which root about in pools and marshes, can be kept in captivity. …
>
> <sup>Translation: Forster & Heffner, [Loeb Classical Library 407](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/columella-agriculture/1941/pb_LCL407.397.xml?rskey=W4sS6o&result=1&mainRsKey=JSw185)</sup>

Varro, in his own *Rerum Rusticarum* [3.3.3](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/varro-agriculture/1934/pb_LCL283.441.xml?result=2&rskey=fgJAUA), quotes a playful debate about what constitutes a *villa,* in which one Cornelius "Blackbird" Merula says that *querqedulae* need both land and water—important to know if you're keeping them in an enclosure. In *De Lingua Latina* [5.79](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/varro-latin_language/1938/pb_LCL333.77.xml?rskey=lo9pDu&result=1&mainRsKey=gUgkeJ), Varro claims that the *querqedula* gets its name from its cry (or some quality), and that the word originates from Greek κερκήδης. You can judge for yourself [here](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Green-winged_Teal/sounds). Note the pitch mark in the Greek word; the pitch and rhythm do seem to match the male call.

So, **querquedula** is definitely a farm animal and definitely Classically attested.

Comment: Thanks for the research! In the absence of any hint of antiquity for qualea (in any of its forms), I'll have to go with querquedula, no matter how strange that sounds. I am filing away the Medieval words for quail for later, though, so it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

While checking something in the *queror* entry in *OLD*, I just happened to glance down and see *querquēdula*, 'a kind of water-fowl, prob. the teal.' It's not exactly a barnyard animal, though. Or maybe it would hang out with the ducks – or I should say *other* ducks, since the teal is a type of duck.

Otherwise, aside from *quadriiugus* and *quadrupes*, there's also *quadriga*, which can refer to the team of four horses that pulls a *quadriga*. In addition, *OLD* tells me that, in the plural, it can mean 'chariot-horses.'

Answer (score 4):

After a quick review of letter Q in L&S, I only found what cnread found: [querquedula](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DQ%3Aentry%20group%3D6%3Aentry%3Dquerquedula), which is apparently a kind of duck.

Other near misses (besides the already mentioned *quadrupes*, *quadriiugus* and *quadriga*):

- [Quelea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-billed_quelea), scientific name Quelea quelea, an african bird, first described in the XVIII century by Linneus as a species, later become a whole genus, present in most of Africa south of the Sahara. (Perhaps the Romans knew it by that name?) It is the most numerous and destructive bird species in the world. It has been argued that there is a link between *quelea* and the *coturnices* (quails) mentioned at the end of [Num 11](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_vt_numeri_lt.html#11). It has also been argued that the name comes from an aboriginal African name. ([Source](https://books.google.cl/books?id=-RfSBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA328&pg=PA328#v=onepage&q&f=false).) *Thanks Ben Kovitz*.
- [Quercus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquercus), the oak tree. I know a tree is not an animal, but just maybe it fits as a second best for someone looking for this question in the future.
- As far as I understand L&S, [*quadrigarius*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DQ%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dquadrigarius1) is applied to the racing horse: *pulvis quadrigarius*, e.g. in Vegetius's [Digesta Artis Mulomedicinae](https://ia601408.us.archive.org/35/items/pvegetirenatidi00lommgoog/pvegetirenatidi00lommgoog.pdf) (p. 140 of the pdf, 85 in printed page numbers)

Comment: Two factoids learned during my own recent googling (which you're welcome to include in your answer if you see fit): (1) _Quelea quelea_ is the most numerous bird species in the world—and the most destructive. (2) Linnaeus used _quelea_ as the specific difference, not the genus (i.e. as a modifier, not the noun), and it's not clear if he was likening _Q. quelea_ to a Bible story involving numerous and destructive quail or drawing upon an African word—or at least that's what I read in [these two paragraphs](https://books.google.com/books?id=-RfSBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA328&pg=PA328#v=onepage&q=quelea).

Comment: @BenKovitz Yeah, Wikipedia's vague on the etymology, too. I love the way it discusses the etymology of "quelea" and then, in the very next section, says that the bird is called a "kwelea domo-jekundu" in Swahili without any mention of which name came first.

Comment: Some more amateur but fanatic googling reveals… The genus was named in 1850 by H.G. Reichenbach, according to [this](http://www.ubio.org/NZ/detail.php?uid=172507&d=1) and other sources; depicted [here](https://archive.org/stream/dievollstandig211836reic#page/n175/mode/2up), defined [here](https://archive.org/stream/conspectusg1218501865bona#page/444/mode/2up/search/quelea). Linnaeus named the species _Emberiza quelea_ [here](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/727083#page/196/mode/1up). _Emberiza_ apparently means "[bunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunting_(bird))".

Comment: Thanks for the research! I am planning on doing something with trees soon, but *quercus* is already known. If you find any direct evidence for *quelea* before the Medieval period, though, that would be a more desirable word than *querquedulea*.