# Do any common/barnyard Latin animal names start with vocalic I?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, animals

Like with [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4333/do-any-latin-animal-names-start-with-q), I'm looking for common or barnyard animals attested in the Classical period, but Late Latin or early Medieval Latin that has a good case of going back to the Classical period would suffice.

I do know two that went back to Greek (*ictis* and *ibis*, the former probably sufficing), but I'm hoping for more examples.

Comment: Do you prefer original Latin names rather than Greek names adopted in Latin?

Comment: @Rafael That would be preferable, but I'll take common but from Greek over rare but native Latin if it came down to it. Thanks for looking so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[so far, up to entry group 8 of around 70 in L&S, currently in 'im-' in alphabetical order. Most of letter i- is made of in-, which is dominated by in- and inter- prefixed words less likely to be animals]*

#### *Arguably* common animals starting with i-:

- **[ibex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dibex)**, -icis, m. *a kind of goat, the [chamois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamois)*.
- **[ictis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dictis)**, -idis, f.  *a kind of weasel*. From Greek.

#### Other (non-barnyard animals or near misses)

*(this list will probably be deleted if the previous gets large enough)*

- [ibis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DI%3Aentry+group%3D2), -is & -idis (irregular declension), f. *the ibis, a bird held sacred by the Egyptians*. From Greek.
- [ichneumon](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dichneumon), -onis,  m. *Egyptian rat* - wild. Also the name of an insect. From Greek.
- [ichthyŏcolla](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dichthyocolla), -ae, f. *A kind of sturgeon, the [huso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huso)*. From Greek.
- [icterus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D2%3Aentry%3Dicterus), -i, m. *A yellow bird*, seemingly a hapax legomenon. From Greek.